# How does the compile gcc_4.8.1 knows where to look for headers?

Tags: gcc, g++

I am calling the g++ compiler on a .cpp file withouth specifying any include directoryes or without setting any path environment variables. How does it know to use the header (e.g. signal.h) from a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few default include directories:

1. `/usr/include/` - standard libraries, system headers and all installed dev packages
2. `/usr/lib/gcc/<platform>/<version>/include/` - compiler internal includes for builtins, basic platform types etc.

Additionally, lot of software that is installed manually, goes into `/usr/local/include/` but this is usually not default location for compiler to look into.

You can specify additional path with `-I<path>` parameter if needed.